# Language pack in large codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

As my project has grown, so to has the language file.  I am over 4000 lines now (400kb of storage)

Is it more efficient to have many small language files, related to the classes being loaded, or just lump all the language entries into one file as I have done?

Is there a benefit to pre-sorting the language pack entries?

Oh, at the moment I am only using English, the language pack is mainly to abstract text from code content in the models.

Answer (score 1):

Basically codeigniter's language files are included in your current controller , this just adds an associative array , now if your language file has large amount of data and if you find a way to divide it into smaller files , it will be helpful because it is easier to retrieve a value from smaller associative array as opposed to a large one , the difference will be minute but there will be a difference .i don't think there will be any difference if the language pack is sorted , i think this is similar to having an associative array in your php file and then trying to get one of its values , the time taken will be the same if the array is sorted or not

Comment: thanks, it also depends on coding style to an extent as well.  fragmenting the language pack entries could make the code more transportable across projects, but that can be achieved by sorting the entries and using common prefixes.